# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character ... when sending email

Tags: beautifulsoup, smtp

I'm building one of the e-commerce websites in Turkey (Hepsiburada) price tracker. The program sends an e-mail when prices are below with your BUY PRICE.

Unfortunately, when executing the program I've got this error.

```
msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is my entire code.

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib


# Hepsiburada Product URL (You can change the product which you want to buy.)
PRODUCT_URL = ""
BUY_PRICE = 3000  # Type buy price in Turkish Lira (TRY).

# Edit this section with your own information.

YOUR_SMTP_ADDRESS = ""
YOUR_EMAIL = ""
YOUR_PASSWORD = ""

# Head over to (http://myhttpheader.com) and replace your "User-Agent" and "Accept-Language".
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9"
}

response = requests.get(url=PRODUCT_URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

price = soup.find(id="offering-price").get_text()
# price_without_currency = price.split(",")[0]
#
# price_as_float = float(price)

title = soup.find(class_="product-name").get_text().strip()

# When product goes on sale and the price below to your BUY_PRICE, it sends an E-Mail to you.

if price:
    message = f"{title} is now {price}"
    print(message)

    with smtplib.SMTP(YOUR_SMTP_ADDRESS, port=587) as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        result = connection.login(user=YOUR_EMAIL, password=YOUR_PASSWORD)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=YOUR_EMAIL,
            to_addrs=YOUR_EMAIL,
            msg=f"Subject:Hepsiburada Price Alert!\n\n{message}\n{PRODUCT_URL}"
        )
```

Can you help me? Where am I stuck?

Comment: Nothing in your code calls `_fix_eols` so we can't see which part is failing. Please [edit] to provide a full traceback, ideally with some debugging information to identify the problematic string, too. The proper solution is to use `EmailMessage` to construct a valid MIME message; pasting random strings together only works for trivial SMTP messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP requires the input message to be a valid RFC5322 (née RFC822) message. You can do this by hand with very simple US-ASCII strings, but the proper solution is to use the `email` module to assemble a valid message for `smtplib`. This takes care of properly formatting and encapsulating any problematic content (including, but not limited to, characters outside the old 7-bit US-ASCII character set, lines longer than approximately 1000 characters, binary payloads, etc etc etc).

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

...
if price:
    email = EmailMessage()
    email['from'] = YOUR_EMAIL
    email['to'] = YOUR_EMAIL
    email['subject'] = 'Hepsiburada Price Alert!'
    email.set_content(f"{title} is now {price}\n{PRODUCT_URL}")

    with smtplib.SMTP(YOUR_SMTP_ADDRESS, port=587) as connection:
        # some servers require ehlo() here
        connection.starttls()
        # some servers even require a second ehlo() here
        connection.login(user=YOUR_EMAIL, password=YOUR_PASSWORD)
        connection.send_message(email)
```

You'll notice that this is basically a copy/paste of the standard example in the [`email` examples documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html). Many on-line examples document an older `email.Message` API which was standard before Python 3.6 but which should now be avoided for any new code.